# Read voice from Raspberry Pi values (ADC)

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, adc

Hello I'm using ADC to read voice (from client 1) then I send it to a server from which client 2 can read it. I tried to register values I got in an array and read it through windows media player to be sure that sound is well recorded but I found nothing.

Any help please about which type of values should be in the file and how to read it well.

Values in the file are like this :

4163
87401
39840
34224
8410
39539
84134
34412
40238
93974
7434
41739
34023
83412
41742
73903
93374
40341
24264
2400
42041
4174
22406
40939
93884
8419
37041
73933
77410
40745
44044
2385
39440
74114
13405
43940
14244
4455
41836
23993
83435
36738
63964
11397
38140
74044
12366
38041
24034
31403
38938
13954
17407
42340
23883
79398
39644
34183
99391...

Comment: What file is that? Is it a wav file or are you simply saving it in text format?

Comment: just saving ADC values in text file , I found that.

Comment: You must save these values as a wave file. Do you know Python? It's fairly easy with it.

Comment: I did posted some minimal example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Python you can try the following to convert the raw samples stored in text, to the wave file. Please note that you must know the sampling frequency of your signal and samples are assumed to be *int16*.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavf
import numpy as np
from sys import argv

def txt2wav(in_f, out_f, fs):
    txtdata = np.genfromtxt(in_f, dtype='int16')
    wavf.write(out_f, int(fs), txtdata)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) != 4:
        print("usage: txt2wav.py input.txt out.wav samp_freq")
    elif len(argv) == 4:
        txt2wav(*argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thank  you jojek , this helped me so much.